# Configure a network interface into promiscuous mode

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, vmware, interface

I am working on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server on VMware Workstation. I need to configure my network interface to work in promiscuous mode.

This is my configuration:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
up ip address add 0/0 dev $IFACE
up ip link set $IFACE up
up ip link set $IFACE promisc on

down ip link set $IFACE promisc off
down ip link set $IFACE down
```

When I execute

```
netstat -i
```

the flag is `BMRU`.

Is my configuration correct or do I need to execute some extra commands?

Comment: You need to know if your network card supports promiscuous mode, not all do. As for the configuration it looks correct

Comment: Since you're using VMWare, I'd also check to make sure you've set the proper adapter configuration on the VM itself. Most VM software suites allow you to set your virtual network adapter to "promiscuous mode" via setup.

Comment: you are right. It looks like my virtual machine can't write on VMNET0 so i have to change permissions on vmnet0 file. But When i execute `ls /dev/ ` i can't find vmnet0. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well the problem is not in the network card because VMware always enables promiscuous mode for virtual interface. But the problem is within the configuration. It is not enough to enable promiscuous mode in the interface file. I had to add this line:

```
ifconfig eth1 up
ifconfig eth1 promisc
```

in the `/etc/rc.local` file because when i restart the network service, eth1 is set down. So adding this lines would tell the os to not shutdown eth1.

Comment: And disable promiscuous mode?

Comment: @e-info128 `ifconfig eth1 -promisc`  (see @vicky's answer https://askubuntu.com/a/662889/269645)

Answer (score 27):

Your interface is not in promiscous mode. Use:

```
ip link set eth1 promisc on
```

The flag will be updated to `BMPRU`. Flag details are as follows:

- `B` flag is for broadcast
- `M` flag is for multicast
- `P` flag is for promisc mode
- `R` is for running
- `U` is for up

Answer (score 12):

enable promiscuous mode

```
vikram@vikram-Lenovo-G580:~$ sudo ifconfig eth0 promisc
vikram@vikram-Lenovo-G580:~$ netstat -i
Kernel Interface table
Iface   MTU Met   RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR  Flg
eth0       1500 0     26631      0      0 0         27143      0      0      0 BMPRU
```

disable promiscuous mode

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 -promisc
sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog
kernel: [ 2155.176013] device eth0 left promiscuous mode

netstat -i
Kernel Interface table
Iface   MTU Met   RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
eth0       1500 0     29172      0      0 0         29850      0      0      0 BMRU
```